# PHP mail() not sending, but no exception thrown

Tags: cakephp, smtp, cakephp-2.0, php

I'm using CakePHP to send an email. My controller code looks like:

```
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $email = new CakeEmail();
            $email->from(array('noreply@mydomain.com' => 'My Domain'));
            $email->to($this->request->data['User']['email']);
            $email->subject('My Domain Confirmation');
            $email->replyTo('noreply@mydomain.com');
            $email->sender('noreply@mydomain.com', 'My Domain');
            $email->emailFormat('html');
            $email->template('confirmation');
            $email->send();
            $email->viewVars(array(
                'name' => $this->request->data['User']['username'],
                'id' => $this->User->getLastInsertID(),
                'code' => $this->request->data['User']['confirm_code']));
        }
```

I also included at the top of this controller:
`App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');`

If I print_r on $email->send(), I get:

```
Array
(
    [headers] => From: My Domain
Reply-To: noreply@mydomain.com
X-Mailer: CakePHP Email
Date: Thu, 23 Feb 2012 00:40:00 -0800
Message-ID: <4f45fb60a0fc46cd926f305a32396397@mydomain.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
    [message] => 



    Hi there,


Welcome to my site! While you can now vote on submissions and leave comments, your own submissions will be screened and not appear to the public until you click on the confirmation link below:

Click here to confirm your account

We hope to see you around and thanks for joining the community!
```

So it's obviously using my html email template and passing the right variables to it, and throwing no exceptions. So I decided to just do a basic mail() test within one of my view files e.g.:

```
$to = "mytestemail@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Which echoed "Mail Sent.", but nothing actually came to my mailbox. I checked my file in `/var/spool/mail/root` and the last email sent was on the same server on Jan. 9, 2012. So it's definitely worked before. I just recently upgraded to Cake 2.0, but this doesn't explain why plain ol' `mail()` isn't working.

What other debugging methods can I check to make sure it's not my server preventing the email from being sent?

Comment: Do you have the correct smpt settings (port,..) configured?

Comment: Is your MTA running? If not, you will see exactly this behaviour (and all mails sent, when you start it)

Comment: have a look in the apache error log (but if it is there you should have seen it) and in the mail error log

Comment: Check your apache log and also make you add on top of your PHP file `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to make sure you get notices and warnings as well.

Comment: @EugenRieck I think that might be the problem. I'm running Fedora 14. How can I check to make sure it's running?

Comment: Depending on what MTA you are running - postfix and sendmail are used quite often. try `/etc/init.d/postfix status`

Comment: @EugenRieck wow looks like postfix was stopped. I just started it and got an influx of email. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's mail() won't throw any exceptions. You need to check the return status. If that's false, then your MTA isn't accepting mail. Even if it returns true, [that doesn't actually mean much of anything](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-returnvalues).

Take a look at the mail logs in /var/log/. Hopefully those can help you figure out more.

Answer (score 0):

also check your firewall settings. sometimes it stops all outgoing smtp requests if not from specific sources.

Answer (score 0):

The server you are running your Cake app on probably requires (SMTP) authentication before it allows you to send anything, which is a pretty common configuration.

Copy the `app/Config/email.php.default` file to `app/Config/email.php` and adjust it to match your setup (usually it's just localhost and you can use one of your mailbox logins for authentication).

Also see [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#configuration) on this subject.

Comment: The weird thing is, this same server has been sending mail from other folder (it's a VPS that hosts multiple websites). I was just checking to see if those other websites can still send mail, and nothing. So odd. It's like it shut off or something. I think this problem stems from MTA not being setup (even though I thought it was).